# Display popup below selected UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working to display popup which should be display below to selected cell.

I have two view controller, both contains `UICollectionView`. So when I select cell from first view controller I want to display popup with animation exactly below selected cell.

I have tried following code to display it.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if self.signupFirstStepVC != nil {
        self.signupFirstStepVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.signupFirstStepVC = nil
    }

    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! MainCategoryCVC
    collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)    
    self.signupFirstStepVC = SignupFirstStepVC.viewController()

    let viewFrame = self.signupFirstStepVC?.view.frame

    self.signupFirstStepVC?.view.frame = CGRect(x: viewFrame!.origin.x, y: cell.lblCategoryName.frame.maxY, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height - 100)    

    UIView.transition(from: cell, to: self.signupFirstStepVC!.view, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) { (success) in
        self.view.addSubview(self.signupFirstStepVC!.view)
    }    
}
```

This code worked, but not display proper view as I have expected.

**Output:**

[image: Add Hobbies]

You can see in above image, my popup is added, but origin start from `UICollectionView`'s origin instead of `cell`'s `lblCategoryName`'s `maxY`.

**Expected:**

[image: Expected Add Hobbies]

Comment: Kumar You just want your popup view below the selected cell of collectionview right?

Comment: @DarshanPatel, Yes.

Comment: try heihgt property insetead of maxY  here cell.lblCategoryName.frame.maxY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert rect according to superview.

```
let theAttributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
let cellFrameInSuperview = collectionView.convert(theAttributes.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
```

Now you have frame according to its superview.

set the frame of view controller using `cellFrameInSuperview`  property

TIP: You should add view controller as child view controller and then add subview to properly manage the view life cycle.

**EDIT**

Please ignore typo

```
self.signupFirstStepVC?.view.frame = CGRect(x: cellFrameInSuperview!.origin.x, y: cellFrameInSuperview.maxY, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height - 100)
```

Comment: I have tried this code, but it is making my view size as per cell size which is not requirement.

Comment: @MayurKarmur You just have to use maxY position  from this frame, if you don't need height ignore it

Comment: Please check this, there are some space due to height of cell is more and bottom constraint of label is `greater than or equal`.  https://imgur.com/a/woi2Ask

Comment: Is it possible to pop up display below label using above code, what changes I need to do ?

Comment: @MayurKarmur  Please use this code  `cell.lblTitle.superview!.convert(cell.lblTitle.frame, to: self.view).maxY`

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this

```
let viewFrame = cell?.frame           
self.signupFirstStepVC?.view.frame = CGRect(x: viewFrame!.origin.x, y: viewFrame?.maxY ?? 0.0, width: collectionView.frame.size.width, height: collectionView.frame.size.height - 100)
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Do let me know if still this solution not resolved your issue. Thanks

Comment: Not working this code, popup display at same place.

Comment: @MayurKarmur Please check my updated answer. I have update viewFrame code.

Comment: I have tried above code, it's display now below, but not proper.

Comment: Can you send me screenshot so I will get idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191957/discussion-between-darshan-patel-and-mayur-karmur).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to add `self.view.safeAreaInsets.top` with the maxY.

**Code Work :**

```
    let topDisplaceHeight =  self.view.safeAreaInsets.top

    let cell = colView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    let pWidth : CGFloat = self.view.bounds.width - 40
    let pHeight : CGFloat = 300

    self.viewPopup.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.width/2 -  pWidth/2,
                                                  y: (cell?.frame.maxY)! + topDisplaceHeight ),
                                  size: CGSize(width: pWidth, height: pHeight))


    self.view.addSubview(self.viewPopup)
```

**Output : iPhone XR**

[image]

**Output : iPhone SE**

[image]